# Getting TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported in webdriverIO javascript with node-fetch

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, node-fetch

how can we append baseURL to relatives URLS as I am not able to convert it to string also .
please guide me on below solution:

```
const links = await $$('a');

   console.log("count of the links are",testURLS.length);

   const urls= await links.map(link => link.getAttribute('href'));

    const requests = urls.map(url =>fetch(url));
    
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests);

    const statusCodes = responses.map(response => response.status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`link.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/href), not `.getAttribute('href')`, and you'll get the resolved URL.